# Разместить несколько полигонов на карту Google Maps из базы

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

помещаю координаты полигонов в массив
в дампе показывает

```
[{lat:50.015104,lng:36.17412} , {lat:50.0001,lng:36.16382} , {lat:49.987078,lng:36.197466}],[ {lat:50.022345,lng:36.203303} , {lat:50.011977,lng:36.200213} , {lat:50.014845,lng:36.219782} , {lat:50.021242,lng:36.220125} , {lat:50.02411,lng:36.212229} , ]
```

это два полигона, далее передаю в JS -> `var alltab = <?=$alltab; ?>;`

вывожу на карту

```
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.988546, 36.233000),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoomControl: true
    });

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var arraypoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [alltab],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    name: 'Полигон', 
    map: map
});
      google.maps.event.addListener(arraypoly, 'click', showArrays);
      arraypoly.setMap(map);
```

в итоге, выводится только один полигон из базы (при условии что он один в массиве, если два и более полигонов - не выводит ничего...)
подскажите как сделать грамотную переборку массива и вывод всех полигонов?
сильно не пинайте, только учусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полигон создается из массива координат. Если вам нужно несколько полигонов - создавайте их последовательно, например так:

```
const poligons = [[{lat:50.015104,lng:36.17412} , {lat:50.0001,lng:36.16382} 
, {lat:49.987078,lng:36.197466}],[ {lat:50.022345,lng:36.203303} , 
{lat:50.011977,lng:36.200213} , {lat:50.014845,lng:36.219782} , 
{lat:50.021242,lng:36.220125} , {lat:50.02411,lng:36.212229} , ]]

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       zoom: 12,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.988546, 36.233000),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       zoomControl: true
   });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    poligons.forEach(poligon => {
        const poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: poligon,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            name: 'Полигон', 
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', showArrays);
        poly.setMap(map);
    });
}
```